# Component Implementation in a ECS with structs

Tags: c#, generics, static-members, entity-component-system

**Goal:**

I am trying to implement an Entity Component System and I'm stuck with my component implementation. I intend to have a generic component type which contains a static Bit for each component there is, e.g. components of type Position have Bit=0, components of type Sprite have Bit=1, etc. A component should only consist of the values it holds therefore I started with structs. Following is my attempt on this (not working code):

```
    struct Position : Component<Position> //this does not work in c#
    {
        public int x, y;
    }

    internal struct ComponentBit
    {
        public static int bitCounter = 0;

    };

    public struct Component<T>
    {
        public static readonly int bit;

        static Component()
        {
            bit = ComponentBit.bitCounter++;
        }

        public int GetBit()
        {
            return bit;
        }
    }
```

After that I found out that structs cannot be inherited from so I tried to change the structs to classes which worked.

**Question:**

Is there any way to implement these features with structs as it would be possible in C++ (templates)? I'd like to keep them as value types instead of reference types for implementation/performance reasons later on.

**Edit1:**

The intended usage I'd like to have is:

```
Position pos = new Position(x, y);
int bit1 = pos.GetBit(); // or
int bit2 = Position.bit; // both should be possible
```

Comment: Just don't use inheritance. Edit: It looks like `Component<T>` is intended to work as a type to int dictionary. You can do that. There is no need to inherit from it.

Comment: @Theraot I'm a bit confused about your comment. That would mean that I have to duplicate the code for each component I have, no? On the other hand, how would I be able to identify the variable as a Component then? Edit: I guess I could use an interface IComponent for the second question.

Comment: I do not see a need for duplication. As per identifying what is a component... just treat every struct as a possible component. If the programmer is trying to add a struct to an entity, any struct to any entity (with whatever API you create for that), then it is a component. Edit: you then query the bit using the type.

Comment: @Theraot If I understand you correctly this means I need to manually "register" each struct as a component, e.g. Component<Position>, in order to set the bit or have separate logic to handle this. My initial idea was that all this is done automatically whenever a new component is instantiated. See my Edit1 in the question for that. Guess I have to change the design then. If you want you can write an answer that I can accept (though I will wait a bit for further suggestions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to not try to use inheritance.

Any struct is a possible valid component, for example:

```
struct Position
{
    public int X, Y;

    public Position(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Now, you can still have `Component<T>` to work as a type to int dictionary (`Dictionary<Type, int>`). Although, I'm going with least changes to make this work:

```
internal static class ComponentBit
{
    public static int bitCounter = 0;

};

public static class Component<T>
{
    public static readonly int bit; // This is static, it has a value per type T

    static Component()
    {
        bit = ComponentBit.bitCounter++;
    }

    public static int GetBit()
    {
        // This method only accesses static members, it can be static
        // Thus, no instance of T is needed
        return bit;
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
Position pos = new Position(x, y);
int bit1 = Component<Position>.GetBit();
int bit2 = Component<Position>.bit;
```

No idea why you want two ways of doing this, yet there you go.

---

Alright, now I will take the freedom to do bigger changes... with that in mind, if you want type inference you can do this:

```
public static class Component
{
    internal static int bitCounter = 0;

    public static int GetBit<T>()
        where T : struct // We only accept structs here
    {
        return Component<T>.bit;
    }

    public static int GetBit<T>(this ref T value)
        where T : struct // We only accept structs here
    {
        // This is an extension method.
        // It will appear as a method on any valid T (which is all structs)
        // The type T will be infered from the instance.
        // Passing the struct as a reference to avoid a copy
        _ = value; // discard value
        return GetBit<T>();
    }
};

internal static class Component<T>
    where T : struct // We only accept structs here
{
    internal static readonly int bit;

    static Component()
    {
        bit = Component.bitCounter++;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var pos = new Position(x, y);
var bit1 = Component.GetBit<Position>();
var bit2 = pos.GetBit();
```

Yes, the above code compiles and runs. See it in [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Note: I would consider nesting `Component<T>` in `Component`.